# ElasticSearch not recognizing date type, shown as String type

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, date-format

ElasticSearch version: 6.3

mapping definition:

`ES_DOCTYPE = {
    "properties": {
        "UsageEndDate": {"type": "date", "format": "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},
        "UsageStartDate": {"type": "date", "format": "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
    }
}`

json data:

`{
 'UsageEndDate': '2018-08-01 02:00:00',
 'UsageStartDate': '2018-08-01 01:00:00'
}
{
 'UsageEndDate': '2018-08-02 02:00:00',
 'UsageStartDate': '2018-08-02 01:00:00'
}`

create index:

`es.index(index="test", doc_type='test', body=ES_DOCTYPE)`

send data:

`helpers.streaming_bulk(es, documents(), index="test", doc_type='test', chunk_size=1000)`

hi I did my work google searching around, but maybe the keyword is too general so I didn't get much.

As I read documentation, ES should be able to find date format automatically, but even I add mapping definition, those `UsageStartDate` or `UsageEndDate` still shown as `string` when I view them in Kibana.

Is there anything I'm missing?

thank you very much :)

Comment: did you tried to delete the index from kibana and add it ? another solution is to edit your field on kibana interface; just when you add your index you can edit the type of any field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself,

`dynamicTemplate = {
    "properties": {
        "UsageEndDate": {"type": "date", "format": "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},
        "UsageStartDate": {"type": "date", "format": "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
    }, "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "notanalyzed": {
                "match": "*",
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}`

and put mapping definition first, then send data to ElasticSearch

```
es.indices.put_mapping(index="test", doc_type='test', body={'test': dynamicTemplate})

es.index(index='test-index', doc_type='tweet', body=ES_DOCTYPE)
```

Answer (score -1):

[According to the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/date.html) ElasticSearch works with `date` in the following way. Internally it stores them as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch. For output Dates will always be rendered as string.

Quote from the documentation:

> JSON doesn’t have a date datatype, so dates in Elasticsearch can either be:
>
> - strings containing formatted dates, e.g. "2015-01-01" or "2015/01/01
>     12:10:30".
> - a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.
> - an integer representing seconds-since-the-epoch.
>
> Internally, dates are
>   converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified) and stored
>   as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.
>
> Queries on dates are internally converted to range queries on this
>   long representation, and the result of aggregations and stored fields
>   is converted back to a string depending on the date format that is
>   associated with the field.